# System.Web.Security in Console application

Tags: security, web, system, console-application, formsauthentication

I want to generate HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile in console application.
It is done using the following class in web application

```
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(str_value, "md5")
```

But System.Web.Security class is not available in console application
Can anybody tell me an alternative method to this
Or 
Is it possible to import System.Web.Security class in console application
Any help would be appreciated

Thank You
Suvidha

Answer (score 3):

Include the System.Web Reference.

Right-click "References" in the Solution Explorer under your project and click "Add Reference."

Then under Assemblies --> Framework, select System.Web and click OK.